# Meaning of $K'[\cdot]$ when $K$ is an symmetric Onsager (matrix) operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is from the section 5.2 of the monograph "*Entropy Methods for Diffusive Partial Differential Equations*" written by Ansgar J$\ddot{\text{u}}$ngel. To be specific, I do not know what does it mean when the author stated (in page 117) $$(\partial_t K)\,\xi = K'[\partial_t \nu]\,\xi.$$ Also, it is very confusing to me as well when he said (again in page 117) $$ Q= -K'[\cdot]\,\log\rho - K\,\nu^{-1}.$$ Clearly $K$ is a matrix (operator) of infinite dimension, so $K\,\nu^{-1}$ should be a matrix as well. But $\log\rho$ is an infinite dimensional vector, so how could the term $-K'[\cdot]\,\log\rho$ become a matrix then? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency of the operators on $\nu$ is implicit at various places. For instance
$$
  K = K(\nu) = G \Lambda(\nu) G^\top
$$
with $\Lambda_i(\nu)$ as defined in (5.9).

The notation $K'$ is the Riesz representative of the Fréchet derivative of $K$, sometime also called variational derivative. This is defined in our case for any possible tangent direction $s\in T_\nu \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$, formally $s\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ of mean zero if $\nu_i >0$ for all $i$, by
$$
  K'(\nu)[s]_{i,j} := \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{K(\nu+h s)_{i,j} - K(\nu)_{i,j}}{h}
$$
Hence, in this case
$$
K'(\nu)[s] = G\Lambda(\nu)[s] G^\top . 
$$
Since, by definition $\partial_t \nu \in T_\nu \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$, we have the first identity $\partial_t K(\nu) \xi = K(\nu)[\partial_t \nu] \xi$.

We can further simplify this, by considering $K$ as a function on the whole of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and hence have the *partial derivatives* $\partial_{\nu_j} K(\nu) = K'(\nu)[e_j]$, where $e_j$ is the $j$-th unit vector. This is given in the present setting by $\partial_{\nu_j} K(\nu)=G \partial_{\nu_j} \Lambda(\nu) G^\top$.

Then, we can take the derivative of $(Q\nu)_i = - (K(\nu)\log \rho)_i$ in $\nu_j$ for any $i,j$ and get
$$
  Q_{i,j} = - \partial_{\nu_{j}} \sum_{l} K(\nu)_{i,l} \log \rho_l
= -\sum_l \partial_{\nu_{j}} K(\nu)_{i,l} \log \rho_l - K(\nu)_{i,j} \nu_j^{-1} .
$$
So the notation $K'[\cdot]\log\rho$ refers to the first sum in the above line. The reason is, that $K'(\nu)$ is a tensor of order three and one needs to be careful on its action on a single vector, which is indicated by with the notation $[\cdot]$.